# Sorting/Grouping data by date (day)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website for ads. I want to have a list like this

**Saturday 10/22/2011 (header)**

Product title 1-city - 100$

Product title 2-city - 74$

Product title 3-city - 500$

**Sunday 10/23/2011 (header)**

Product title 4-city - 150$

Product title 5-city - 220$

Product title 6-city - 10$

My code is ordering the list perfectly from newest to the oldest but I want to add something to the while loop to print out the headers (which are in bold) like (Saturday 10/22/2011). **Basically i want to group the lists under the name of the day they were posted on**
here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT post_id,city, title, price, imgurl FROM md_post WHERE category='$cat' AND city='$city' ORDER BY timeStamp desc";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo "<a href='adid.php?id=".$row['post_id']."'>". $row['title']. " - ". $row['price']." - ".$row['city']."</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming timeStamp is a unix timestamp:

```
$sql = "SELECT post_id, city, title, price, imgurl, timeStamp FROM md_post WHERE category='$cat' AND city='$city' ORDER BY timeStamp desc";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if (!isset($dateold) || $dateold != date('d',$row['timeStamp']) {
        echo '<strong>'.date('l  m/d/Y',$row['timeStamp']).</strong><br />;
    }
    echo "<a href='adid.php?id=".$row['post_id']."'>". $row['title']. " - ".$row['price']." - ".$row['city']."</a>";
    $dateold = date('d',$row['timeStamp']);
}
```

when it's not a unix timestamp, but a valid time, you can just change the first appearance of `timeStamp` to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timeStamp)`

Comment: This will work only if every row have different date and will not group entries from the same day under one header... Besides there are missing some `'` so the code will fail with syntax errors and notices about undefined constants

Comment: i cannot upvote. I would thank you this way of course ^_^. It tells me it requires 15 reputation. I am new here

Comment: But you can accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark! You'll get there. Read the faq and have fun on SO!

Comment: It worked but for each $row['timeStamp'], I had to make it -> strtotime($row['timeStamp']) to eliminate some errors

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I have tried the code above, after adding the missing 's, and everything worked even for rows posted on the same day. Maybe because they are not actually the same, they have same day date but different posting time (2011-10-23 13:28:01 != 10-23 15:26:44)

Comment: Unless you moved `$dateold` assignment into `if`, it can not work the way you want - in every iteration `$dateold` is undefined so the header will be printed for all rows.

Comment: you mean into the while-loop! I did that and corrected the ''. Other than that it works fine!

Comment: No, you still have syntax errors. Besides it wouldn't group correctly for two following rows with one month time difference (ex. 2011-10-01 and 2011-11-010) since you are comparing only day of the month from timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

1. add timestamp to your select fields
2. introduce new variable that holds last used timestamp
3. in `while` loop check if date form last used timestamp differs from current row, if so print header based on current row timestamp, assign it to last used timestamp and then print the rest.

Comment: I appreciate your help :) I got it following these steps